# What the metrics names on dropwizard means

Tags: dropwizard

I integrated dropwizards on my machine.

I exposed them but I am looking for information what they means.

for example how can I get the number of requests per sec? any such information is available anywhere coz I couldnt find it on the official site.

thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that **vertx-dropwizard-metrics** are using some customised meters. In their javadoc you can find the following:

```
/**
 * A throughput metric, wraps a {@link Meter} object to provide a one second instant
 * throughput value returned by {@link #getValue()}.
 *
 * @author <a href="mailto:julien@julienviet.com">Julien Viet</a>
 */
```

For more details see [this commit](https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-dropwizard-metrics/commit/e26bb5239380afcd9ded7d7de518b38b16bc6826).
So their documentation is little out-of-date.

Comment: The problem is that I dont understand the meanings of the metrics. I need to understand what they present

Comment: IMO (using the info in JavaDoc) the `InstantThroughput` means the total number of processed calls in the last second i.e. how many calls the software have processed very recently. Probably you have to play with the load and observe how the various metrics are changing.

Answer (score 4):

All the "out of the box" metrics are exposed on the admin port. You can check them there. (`http://localhost:<admin-port>/metrics`)

For example, the number of requests can be fetched from the key: `io.dropwizard.jetty.MutableServletContextHandler.requests`

The ones specific to the web server, will be exposed via jetty. You will also be able to get metrics like 2xx-responses, 4xx-responses, 5xx-responses, etc.

You can always refer to this manual if you want to add your own custom ones: https://dropwizard.github.io/metrics/3.1.0/getting-started/

Here's also an article about metrics in dropwizard: http://nbsoftsolutions.com/blog/guide-and-explanation-for-metrics-in-dropwizard

Comment: I understand but there are some simple attributes that I have no clue what they mean. for example: InstantThroughput   what it means? please check my question I added screenshot

Comment: That doesn't look like an attribute from the Snapshot class.  https://dropwizard.github.io/metrics/3.1.0/apidocs/index.html?com/codahale/metrics/Snapshot.html You're probably using another library perhaps?

Comment: I am using dropwizard for vertx. I exposed everything via mbeans https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-dropwizard-metrics/blob/master/src/main/asciidoc/java/index.adoc